# Is there any objective criterion to determine the adequate degree of polynomial approximations?

Tags: approximation-theory

I carry out a polynomial function approximation to a load duration curve (monotone decreasing function). I can approximate the load duration curve by using polynomial degrees from 4 to 12. I need an objective criterion to select the degree of polynomial considering a tradeoff between accuracy and included number of parameters in the function. 
Statistically, one can use adjusted $R^2$ or information criterion. But these statistical criteria do not work because the residuals are nonlinear (not suitable for adjusted $R^2$) and also I use least squares (do not have maximum likelihood value). Is there any other criterion to choose the adequate degree of polynomial from $4$th to $12$th degree?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what the non-linearity is that you're referring to.  Can you be explicit about your model?  Least squares coincides with maximum likelihood when errors are independent, normal, and homoscedastic. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: This question might get better answers at stats.stackexchange.com . ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Traditionally one writes either "This criterion is" or "These criteria are".  I.e. "criteria" is the plural of "criterion". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy sorry, the residuals are correlated, not normally distributed and the residuals indicate a nonlinear pattern in the scatter plot. The domain of the function is from 1 to 8760. The model will enable just to read off values corresponding to the values in the domain. The statistical methods cannot help for the selection of the polynomial degree. Information Criteria are AIC, AICc and BIC. Requirement is the validity of  normally distributed residual.

Comment: I suspect one would need more information in order to write any sensible answer to this question. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I need to select the degree of polynomial function which adequately approximates a load duration curve. The problem is that I can not use statistical methods which helps choosing adequate models because the residuals of the regression analysis do not fulfill the required statistical assumptions (diagnostic tests do not validate the fitted curve). However this is not important because the function is defined in a domain and will not be used for forecasting.

Comment: @MichaelHardy The used method here is least squares approximation. The functional approximation is carried according to the mathematics and not according to the statistics. Because although the statistical assumptions are not validated, the function is valid in the interval. I ask for a mathematical way of choosing the degree of polynomial but not statistical.

Comment: @MichaelHardy According to Weierstrass Approximaton Theory, any continuous function can be approximated to any accuracy by a polynomial of high enough degree. I came up with the idea of using mean absolute percentage error, the deviation of area under the curve from the actual area (corresponds to that year's electricity consumption) and the error in approximating highest demand. The best result is using 11th degree polynomial; however compared to a 5th degree polynomial the gain is not that much with respect to the number of parameters used. But this is an arbitrary decision not objective.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Although I can have a basis to compare the accuracy of approximations, I dont have a measure to compare gained accuracy w.r.t number of parameters used in polynomials.